# Use IN & OR operator toigether

Tags: mysql

My SQL query is:

```
                            SELECT * FROM add_legrec_recipe 
                            WHERE name LIKE '%search%' 
                                OR meal_type='08' 
                                OR main_ingredients LIKE '%,12,%' 
                                OR ingredient='03'
                                OR id IN ("12,10,13")
                            ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,5
```

Here every condition field is dynamic but I have hardcoded here for simplicity.
My problem is that IN operator is working fine but query is ignoring the above OR operators and when I remove IN operator then OR operator is working fine.

Also It will be best if I can **add IN operator for all the fields in Table or selected columns**. Unable to use multiple IN operator.

If there is a way to **use Multiple IN operator in single Query**, then that will be the best Solution for me.

Comment: How specifically is this failing?  "It's not working" doesn't really describe the problem.  The only thing we can guarantee about this code is that it does exactly what it's written to do.  What do you *expect* it to do?

Comment: Is id an integer?

Comment: Id is an integer. And about my problem, it is clearly written that when I am adding IN operator, where clause is ignoring conditions above IN operator. And I want to use IN operator for all the columns if possible.

Comment: Could you post a "not simplified" version, as it really is?

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you use the AND operator?

Something like

> SELECT * FROM add_legrec_recipe 
>   WHERE name LIKE '%search%' 
>     OR meal_type='08' 
>     OR main_ingredients LIKE '%,12,%' 
>     OR ingredient='03'
>     AND id IN ("12,10,13")
>   ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,5

Comment: No, I have to use only use OR operator. If possible want to  use IN operator for all the columns, separated by OR operator.

Comment: SELECT * FROM add_legrec_recipe 
WHERE (name LIKE '%search%' 
       OR meal_type = '08' 
    OR main_ingredients LIKE '%,12,%' 
    OR ingredient = '03')
      OR id IN (12, 10, 13)
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,5

Comment: This is giving the same result as my original query by ignoring the Condition above IN operator.